# Reason of MOSFET over current?

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, h-bridge, mosfet-driver, keil

I have a 3 phase inverter H bridge which has 6 MOSFETs (**IPD90N04S4_05**) as shown in the picture.

[image: 3 phase inverter H bridge with 6 MOSFETs]

I have numbered each leg of a MOSFET as 1, 2, 3, 4. The middle leg (number 2) of the MOSFET has been cut and pushed down.

I have found the data sheet:

http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/196/Infineon-IPD90N04S4_05-DS-v01_00-en-1226334.pdf

How can I find out whether MOSFETs are OK or not?

---

**My second question start here.**

I use these MOSFETs with an Infineon chip and my programing environment is Keil Microvision 5.

Earlier I was able to operate the MOSFETs using PWM from the Infineon chip for a BLDC motor application. But all of a sudden , one day when I supply PWM pulses to the gates of the MOSFETs, the error I get (from the debug window of Keil, *screenshot below*) that "external FET source–drain short" for all 6 MOSFETs.

But surprisingly when I check physically with multi-meter the source and drain (leg no 2 and 3) don't show any short.

How is it possible?

[image: (In this picture two MOSFETs are shown as HS2_DS_STS & HS1_DS_STS as 1(short). Similarly remaining four MOSFETs also show Drain-Source status(xx_DS_STS=1) short).]

Comment: which is your question?  ... the title of your post or the last sentence?

Comment: you can do all the numbering that you want, but it is pretty useless when there is no schematic to refer to.

Comment: Is this a board you designed / made?

Comment: The specific device was not mentioned in the question, but it seems that you are using a member of the Infineon TLE987x family (3-phase bridge driver with ARM Cortex-M3 core). It is the registers from *that* device, which you are displaying in the screenshots in your question. Therefore it is *that* device, which is deciding to report (in that register) that the MOSFETs are shorted. It will probably help if you supply links to the manuals for that device, so readers can see how the manufacturer explains the decision-making that causes it to set that status bit.

Comment: Thank you all.I am using Infineon "TLE987x Eval Kit" for BLDC application.My program environment is Keil microvision 5.https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/motor-control-ics/automotive-embedded-power-ics-system-on-chip-/3-phase-bridge-driver-with-integrated-arm-cortex-m3/tle9879qxa40/#!documents

Comment: Thank you very much SamGibson. I think you have some experience with Infineon TLE microcontrollers.  
     
I am adding some more information here. If i switch on the PWM, it shows error message "FET over current" along with “external FET source–drain short”. But physically when i check continuity between source and drain, there is no short. I have been stuck with this problem for last one month unable to figure out whether it is a software problem or hardware problem. From your experience if you could help me to resolve this problem, I will be ever grateful to you.

Comment: @litunbls - I believe I can see some possible misunderstanding about the interpretation of the status bits, but no, I don't have experience with those specific MCUs. To avoid me wasting time writing an analysis which might repeat your work so far, I want to read what you have already considered as possible causes and eliminated during your troubleshooting. I know you were [asking questions](https://www.infineonforums.com/threads/5577-Infineon-TLE9879-Eval-Kit-Bridge-short-problem) on the Infineon Forum, but that site seems to be down. Please update the question & summarise the progress so far.

Comment: @SamGibson-Thank you very much. As you suggest I am summarizing the progress so far. My evaluation board is working for all peripherals except the bridge drive side.I have tried all possible way to start the bridge drive(BRDV) but not succeeded. I have a problem of BRDV CTRL1 register(Bit 28,20,12,4) and BRDV CTRL2 register(Bit 12,4) are showing 1(1=short on external FET detected). These bits are read only bits and after reset they should be 0.

Comment: ....continued.
I have physically checked that there is no short in the motor or in the bridge side. But still for my case above bits are showing 1. I have also followed the procedure described in the datasheet "TLE987xQX-Users-Manual-13-Infineon.pdf" page number 811 to 813. But not able do so. I think unless I reset these bits I will not be able to run the bridge drive(BRDV).

Comment: This is by far the best quality photo of a broken component we have ever seen on this website.

Answer (score 1):

> I have been stuck with this problem for last one month unable to figure out whether it is a software problem or hardware problem.

I don't have your hardware in front of me. However, based on the information you have given, and my own research, I'll give you my hypothesis. I would start by suspecting software, not a genuine hardware fault, for the following reasons:

- a) If the interpretation of a FET source-drain short was valid, as per your interpretation, for all 6 MOSFETs, then you would have needed to damage them all, at the same time.

  Damaging 6 Power MOSFETs so that they are shorted would, in my experience, usually have been obvious (noise, smell, smoke, damage to the device package etc.).
- b) The chances of all 6 Power MOSFETs being damaged (as per your interpretation) is not very likely (if it was just one or two damaged devices being reported, that would be different).
- c) As you have said, you can't actually measure a source-drain short, again suggesting that this is a false report.
- d) In your question's title, you asked for the reason for "MOSFET over current". However the status bits which are set at that point in your code, are *not* for overcurrent. Notice that the status bits which are set in register `CTRL1`, are the `HSx_DS_STS` bits *not* the `HSx_OC_STS` bits, so the detection mechanism is different. It seems that you are trying to perform a Bridge Driver "Off-Diagnosis".
- e) Possible error in the [TLE987xQX User Manual](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-TLE9879QXA40-UM-v01_03-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d4624e24005f014e52ca1628452c) linked from [this page](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/motor-control-ics/automotive-embedded-power-ics-system-on-chip-/3-phase-bridge-driver-with-integrated-arm-cortex-m3/tle9879qxa40/#!documents).

  In section 27.4.1.1.1 ("Preparation") notice how figures 218+219 and 221+222 are identical, yet the text before each of those saying which bits should be set in each figure, are *not* identical. Therefore either the figures or the text are wrong, IMHO. I suspect figures 218+219 are wrong, as the text does not match those.

  Step A in that Bridge Driver "Off-Diagnosis" procedure says:

  > A: All phases must be switched in "Enabled"-state (but not "ON"-state)

  However figures 218+219 (wrongly?) highlight the `DCS_EN` bits **not** the `EN` bits in the `CTRL1` and `CTRL2` registers! So the figures do not match the text.

  After step A, you have to do step B, involving writing to `CTRL3`. *Then* the `DCS_EN` bits should be set later, in step C:

  > C: Enable Drain-Source Current Sources on the High-Side (HSx) drivers

  And only after *that*, you perform step D, clear the `DS_STS` flags, and *check whether they remain clear*:

  > D: Assuming the motor contacts do not have a short to VBAT or to GND, all the DS-Status flags of each phase can be cleared now, and shall stay cleared.

  Therefore I suspect you are being misled about the correct software procedure, due to the contents of figures 218+219 which suggest you set the `DCS_EN` bits at step A (which we can see you doing, where you write `0x09090909` to `CTRL1`, for example). However the User Manual says those bits are set at step C.
- f) There is the possibility of a motor problem, causing all `HSx_DS_STS` *or* all `LSx_DS_STS` bits to be set, as explained in section 27.4.1.1.2 (Detection).

  However since you are reporting all `HSx_DS_STS` *and* all `LSx_DS_STS` bits to be set, then this possibility doesn't make sense. You could investigate running the same test with the motor disconnected. Obviously the "open load" would be reported, but if the `DS_STS` bits are still set, then a disconnected motor can't cause that!
- g) I had a quick look at some sample code from the Infineon site, but (i) I couldn't see any sample code which included that Bridge Driver "Off-Diagnosis" which you are attempting, so I couldn't see what *they* demonstrate as the correct procedure, and (ii) their download licensing would prevent me showing it to you anyway, as the license prohibits public disclosure of code from a download. :-(
- h) At the point in your code that you show in the screenshot (and you might not even be allowed to show that, based on the download license that I saw!) it seems you might be looking at the `CTRL1` status bits after just step A in the procedure. That would be incorrect - you need to perform the other steps before then clearing the `DS_STS` bits and seeing if they remain clear.

  As it says after step A in the User Manual:

  > The DS-Status Flags are still set in this state of the Bridge Driver, but since the Drain-Source-Current Sources are not enabled these flags do not have a meaning yet.

  So before you follow the other steps, including enabling the current sources later, then seeing the `DS_STS` bits "set" **has no meaning** at that point. It seems that you might be making that mistake in the interpretation of those bits (but I can't be sure, based on only that small amount of code visible in the screenshot).

---

I hope that gives you some ideas. As I said at the start, this is just a hypothesis, which I can't test without the hardware.

If possible, try to go back to a version of your code which you know was working, on a date before the first date you believe things "went wrong" (I hope you have some kind of SCM system e.g. Git, SVN etc.).

When the website became viewable again today, I noticed that you weren't getting any replies on the Infineon forums. I suggest you could also contact Infineon support directly through their "Technical Assistance Center (TAC)" if you need more help, or via whichever distributor you are using. Good luck!

Comment: First of all, I would like to thank you verymuch. I have no more forum left where i asked the problem but got any answer including  Infineon forum. Thank you again for taking so much pain in going through the datasheet. Even if Infineon TAC is also saying we are working on my questions for last 1 month.

Comment: I don't know How Infineon like  automotive semiconductor MNC could make so much mistake in their datasheet. I have read in many other mistakes in their data sheet also. They never reply in their forum. Even If so called "TAC" is a third party agency who only receives the query and forward it to Infineon. They never speak or write mail directly.

Comment: @litunbls - I'm sorry to hear about the difficulties getting official support on your problem. I have just one more suggestion: On [this Infineon page](https://www.infineon.com/cms/de/product/power/motor-control-ics/automotive-embedded-power-ics-system-on-chip-/3-phase-bridge-driver-with-integrated-arm-cortex-m3/) they talk about customers getting free support, with **24-hr response** for technical questions, from their "Preferred Design Houses" - and they give a list of those [here](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/partner-network/embedded-power-pdh/). Consider asking the closest one to you?

Comment: Thanks SamGibson, As you are suggesting in (d) over current (LSx/HSx_OC_STS =1) appears if I switch on the Drive in the short condition(HSx/LSx_DS_STS=1). So root cause is HSx/LSx_DS_STS=1.I have taken care of all the things you have suggested but still HSx/LSx_DS_STS bits remain as set.

Comment: Secondly there are 3 cases are pending with infineon regarding this External FET Drain-Source Short issue, Data sheet error etc. But they are telling, we are working on your cases for last 20 days. Earlier two guys Mr. Steve Raym and Mr. Gerrd Belz has written some mails regarding this problem but now there is no reply. What to do in this case?